# How to inflate and listen a custom menu per fragment using NavController?

Tags: java, android, menu

My application uses NavController in this order:

- **MainActivity** is the container of the **NavController**, it have its own menu.
- Home destination is **FragmentMisSecuencias**
- **FragmentMisSecuencias** calls a navigation event to **FragmentSecuencia**

**FragmentSecuencia** needs a custom menu to show options that changes the content of the Fragment.

I managed to change the menu by adding a *destinationChangedListener* on **MainActivity** but it doesn't let **FragmentSecuencia** manage the *onOptionsItemSelected* method.

`MainActivity`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...

   final NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    ...

    final NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    ...
    navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(new NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController controller, @NonNull NavDestination destination, 
                                                         @Nullable Bundle arguments) {
                switch (destination.getId()) {
                    case R.id.nav_dst_secuencia:
                        menu.clear();
                        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_prueba, menu);

                        break;
                }
            }
        });


   ...
}
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        Toast.makeText(this, item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     
        return  false;
    }
```

`FragmentSecuencia`

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.mnu_prueba:
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Menú prueba", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return  true;
        }

        return false;

    }
```

The Toast output is the MenuItem title, not the "Menú Prueba" message. I know that it's because the onOptionsItemSelected of **FragmentSecuencia** is not being called.

I want to know the correct way to implement a custom menu on every NavController destination and handle it from it's own Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Fragments guide for adding items to the app bar](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#ActionBar), fragments have specific APIs for inflating menu items only when that fragment is visible: you should not be using an `OnDestinationChangedListener` for this.

Instead, make sure:

1. Your fragment calls `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` in `onCreate()`
2. Override `onCreateOptionsMenu()` in your fragment to inflate your menu
3. Ensure that your activity calls `super.onOptionsItemSelected()` to pass the selected menu item to fragments for handling